# Visual Studio 2015 Change Console Program's Window Name

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

I was working on a beginner project in C++ on Visual Studio 2015, a calculator and when I find the program, it has the right name, but when I run it, the window title is the file path(C/user/etc.) Is there some way I can change this?

Answer (score 1):

The only bit with `SetConsoleTitle` that could trip you up is [character sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768363/character-sets-not-clear) in regards to the display string. Something like this should work:

```
int main()
{
  SetConsoleTitle( _T( "My Calculator" ) );
  ...
}
```

`_T` is a macro to make the strings character set neutral.