# Omitting u8 prefix for string literals that contain universal character names

Tags: c++, c++11, unicode, utf-8

What will happen if I omit the `u8` prefix for string literals that contain universal character names?

So instead of:

```
u8"\u00a7some-text"
```

I write this:

```
"\u00a7some-text"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without the `u8` prefix, the string will be encoded in the *execution character set* of your platform. The execution character set may be UTF-8 (which is the default on several platforms), but cannot be assumed to always be UTF-8 (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4248640/596219)).

If the execution character set cannot encode a universal character name (or any other value in the string literal), the result is implementation-defined (i.e. it might result in an error or some sentinel value). For example, consider the code:

```
const char* c = "\u00a7";
```

When compiled using GCC 5.3 with `-fexec-charset=ascii`, it fails with the error:

> error: converting UCN to execution character set: Invalid or incomplete multibyte or wide character

This is because U+00A7 cannot be encoded in ASCII. However, using the `u8` prefix:

```
const char* c = u8"\u00A7";
```

Compilation succeeds, and `c` points to the bytes `0xC2` `0xA7` `0x00`.

If you use the `u8` prefix, your string is *guaranteed* to be UTF-8 encoded, regardless of the platform's configuration.